# How to get this density output.

Tags: r, dataset, density-estimation

When I create a density chart I get this output: `plot(density(ab$Assets))`

[image]

But in this online tutorial it looks like this:
http://mars.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/mediawiki/teachwiki/index.php/What_drives_Market_Value:_Analysis_of_the_Forbes_500_US_companies#Distribution_Analysis

[image]

**What is the author doing differently?**

Thank you

Comment: Obviously, both plots show *different* data (the scale of y-axis), so if you have different data, there is no reason to obtain the same density estimates...

Comment: @Tim it's the same data. I'm not sure what he's showing in this graphs exactly

Comment: It looks to me: They used `log(ab$Assets)` for both their density plots for Assets.  The top one was supposed to use just `ab$Assets`, but they put in the incorrect image.

Comment: It is at least log-transformed, so it is not "the same". Use same transformations and same parameters, if this still does not lead to same results, then either you have different data, or you are using other algorithm (or implementation) then the authors.

Comment: @Sal Mangiafico you are right they were using log! The description was wrong! Thank you

Comment: The question seems perfectly clear to me (and the likely answer was obvious merely by looking at the plots); I have reopened. @Sal would you consider posting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not use "the same" data, since the second plot shows log transformed assets, while you plotted raw assets on your first plot. Your page says that the authors have used bandwidth equal to 0.15 to produce the plot, yet if you use `density` function from R, it seems that to get similar plot, you would need something closer to 0.35 when using Gaussian kernel (see below).

[image]